# How to use an inner join with group by or count function

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, group-by, inner-join

I'm use this SQL query to fetch data from a access database

```
SELECT  Absence.date_, stages.name, course.course_name, student.name AS st_name 
FROM  (((Absence INNER JOIN  course ON Absence.course_id = course.ID) 
INNER JOIN       stages ON course.id_stage = stages.ID) 
INNER JOIN     student ON Absence.student_id = student.ID AND stages.ID = student.stage_id`
```

when i wont to group the field or get count of field it show to me this error message

> Tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'Absence.date_' as part of an aggregate function

how can i get number of row ,distinct it by st_name , and group by stage name or course name

Answer (score 1):

For getting the count you should use

```
SELECT  Absence.date_, stages.name, course.course_name, student.name AS st_name, count(*) 
FROM  (((Absence INNER JOIN  course ON Absence.course_id = course.ID) 
INNER JOIN       stages ON course.id_stage = stages.ID) 
INNER JOIN     student ON Absence.student_id = student.ID AND stages.ID = student.stage_id
GROUP BY Absence.date_, stages.name, course.course_name, student.name
```

Comment: it show this message syntax error in from clauses
 i try to remove this quotes student.stage_id`  to student.stage_id

Comment: Yes there was  a typo quotes removied .. i have update the answer.  isthis what you are looking for  ?

Comment: your sql query is work ok ,, but when i add the count(*) it show to me this message error  "   IErroInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL (0×80004005)  "

Comment: Post your new SQL with the Count(*) so we can see where you placed it.

Answer (score -1):

What table contains the field "Absence.date_" ? 
And you do not need to specify "Inner" (or Natural for that matter).

When using aggregate functions (Count(), Sum(), ect) your group by must contain the same list of fields as your select statement. And that error states that either Absence.date_ does not exist as a field in any of the tables in the from clause. But, you have no Group By statement in your query.

Comment: type to  Absence.date_ field is date  
  and i wasn't use inner to this field 
i cut this query from query builder in Database2DataSet.xsd

Comment: in normal  state  without group by statement or count func -  not show to me  any error  
but when i edit the command it show error !

Comment: Sometimes a WYSIWYG editor will spew from it's bowels some interesting things. It looks like possibly absence.data_ shouldn't have a underscore after it. Confirm this. It just looks like you could just select the fields you want, put a count(*) in the select list with those fields, JOIN your tables with those fields and end the statement with a GROUP BY list matching the SELECT list minus the COUNT(*).